# DIV with Circular Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a DIV with circular scrolling. [Here is an example](http://unfold.no/#/contact) of something similar to what I am trying to achieve. In my case, the DIV contains a series of images. [Here is a demo, sans Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/fZBBb/).

My goal is for the DIV to do the following:

- If you scroll to the bottom of the DIV, scrolling would start over again at the beginning, giving the impression of circular scrolling
- The reverse would also be true if you scroll to the top

I don't think it can be achieved my simply jumping from the top to the bottom. Since the content is different (unlike in [the example I gave above](http://unfold.no/#/contact)) the user would see that the DIV was jumping. I am also not interested in carousel plugins that rely on skipping ahead one image at a time. My goal is that the DIV would behave like a standard DIV with overflow set to scroll, only the scrolling would be circular.

Is there any plugin that exists already that accomplishes this?

Comment: I'm not sure what makes you think that scrolling is any different than normal. It seems like you are looking at a "candy cane effect" created by diagonal lines.

Comment: do you happen to notice that the page is miles long? and it starts at the center? and when it reaches the bottom, it jumps back to the top (and vice versa)? it's simple as that, why complicate?

Comment: @GoldenNewby If you use the mouse scroll wheel to scroll through the page, eventually the page shifts from top-to-bottom (or vise versa) and that you can keep scrolling infinitely.  It looks like the top/bottom of the page uses the exact same photo, so when you hit one or the other, the page jumps to the top/bottom so you don't really notice it and it feels like a constant scroll.  If you drag the scroll bar, it doesn't quite give the same effect due to drag limitations.  Prob. a nice effect on touch screens.

Comment: @Joseph Its more complicated because the content in the example I gave is tiled. My content is not.

Comment: @colindunnn the tilt is an **illusion** of the background and content. try to look at the source once in a while and see that there are a lot of sections, absolutely positioned, positioned so they look like they are tilted, in line with the background images with tilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin http://ianli.com/infinitedrag/ does pretty much exaclty what you are looking for. It even has an "axis" for only allowing it to scroll top-bottom and not all over like your first example link.

Comment: This looks promising! I will check back in once I have had a chance to play with it. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, on closer inspection it doesn't appear to be quite what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you explain further as to why Infinite Drag doesn't meet your needs?